# Mailgun logs not complete?

Tags: mailgun

I'm using mailgun to receive emails for me and forward them to my API. I sent 5 emails this morning. All 5 emails arrived at my API. The logs show:

- Routed/Accepted/Failed for the first one
- Routed/Accepted/Failed for the second one
- Nothing for the third one
- Routed for the fourth one
- Nothing for the fifth one

All 5 emails are visible in my google sent folder and my breakpoint was triggered for each send.

What would prevent the logs from being complete?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it can take a long long time for for the mailgun logs to catch up. THey now contain all the messages